# How to disable CPU core on HTC Windows Phone 8x

Tags: htc-8x

I'd like to run my phone single-core.  How would I achieve that?

*Motivation:* On desktop, I commonly go to BIOS and disable 23 cores, leaving one core enabled without HT to prove to software developers that they have a threading bug.

Now that we're getting at "Why" style of discussion, let's ask why not?  Why is it not possible to let go in this case?

Comment: No, you can't - but why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to note here:

1. One of the minimum requirements as specified by Microsoft for a phone to qualify as an official Windows 8 device is to be dual core. This requirement was introduced for Windows Phone 8 and didn't exist for Windows Phone 7.x.
2. For multiple-core processors, the usage of the cores is application dependent. If an application is built to run of multiple threads, that would use multiple cores. If not, it would run on the single core. For instance, an app originally built for Windows Phone 7 would not be able to use the multiple cores on a Windows 8 device.

Having said all of the above, we are now getting closer to answering your question.

You say:

> I'd like my **phone** to run single core...

Assuming you mean you'd like everything on your phone to run on a single core i.e. the OS, the apps, and so forth, **this is not possible** for the reasons stated above.

[For more details information above how Windows Phone (both 7 and 8) handle threading and cores, refer to this official Microsoft documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)